# How to enable the DayDream feature in the Nexus10?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, daydream, samsung-nexus-10

I know that in Android JellyBean 4.2 there's a new feature called DayDream. I want to access it in my Nexus10 but don't know how.

How can I enable and use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what i need to do:

**1st Step:** Launch the Settings app, scroll to the bottom, and tap About Phone.

**2nd Step:**  In the middle of the screen is the listing for Android Version. Tap this item until you see a jelly bean appear on your screen. You can then tap and hold the giant jelly bean until your device vibrates. You should then see interactive beans floating all over your screen. And yes, you can fling them. Go ahead, try it.

**3rd Step :** After doing, this the BeanFlinger Daydream will be unlocked. You can find the Daydream option by going to Settings > Display > Daydream.

Hope it Will Help to all of the  Users Facing this Same kind of Problem.

Comment: For me this only unlocked the BeanFlinger daydream, not the daydream menu itself. Is this really necessary on the Nexus 10?

Comment: @onik You're right: this process is not necessary to turn on daydreams, only to unlock the 'hidden' daydream.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `Settings -> Display -> Daydream` and select your desired daydream. After this, tap `When to daydream` and select when you want it to work.

Now, when you charge/dock the device, leave the screen on and after a while, the daydream will start. For me, this required me not to lock the screen manually by pressing the power button, and disabling `Stay awake` from `Developer options`.

Comment: Thnks for your Support. but i am not getting the option Daydream inside  Settings -> Display.

Comment: Many Many Thnks to you. but i found my Solution on myself.

Answer (score 1):

Tap `Android version` from `Settings -> About Phone` for the few times until big Jelly Bean appears. Then touch and hold this big Jelly Bean. Now, you can see several small Jelly Beans moving on the screen. Finally, you can see `BeanFinger` option on `Settings -> Display -> Daydream`.

Comment: thnks for your support. but i just found my solution same as you have said.